# assertEquals fails for Error implementation but pass for Success one

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, junit4

I have these sealed interface

```
sealed interface Result<out T> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : Result<T>
    data class Error(val exception: Throwable? = null) : Result<Nothing>
}
```

when i tried to `assertEquals` the Success one, it pass. But when it comes to Error one, it will fail even though the content is identical. Here is simple example:

```
@Test
fun testSucess() = runTest {
    whenever(repository.login("email", "password"))
        .thenReturn(someValue)

    val expected = Result.Success(data = someValue)
    val actual = loginUseCase(LoginRequest("email", "password"))

    verify(repository).login("email", "password")
    assertEquals(expected, actual) // this will pass
}

@Test
fun testError() = runTest {
    val exception = RuntimeException("HTTP Error")
    whenever(repository.login("", ""))
        .thenThrow(exception)

    val expected = Result.Error(exception = exception)
    val actual = loginUseCase(LoginRequest("", ""))

    verify(repository).login("", "")
    assertEquals(expected, actual) // this will fail
    assertEquals(expected.toString(), actual.toString()) // this will pass
}
```

What is causing this and what is possible solution to this? I have read some info that it needs `equals()` to be overriden, but i still confused as to why it only happens in Error case only and how to properly override the equals method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Data classes in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) have an implicitly generated `equals` function automatically derived from all their properties.

The problem you are facing is probably due to the fact that the type of your `someValue` has a proper `equals` function, so the equals works for your `Success` and its property `value`. But `Throwable` does not have an `equals` function which means that two `Throwable`s are only equal if they are the same instance, which is obviously not the case for `expected` and `actual` in your test assertion. I can only guess that in `loginUseCase`, the exception is wrapped inside another exception, or a new exception is created based on the one thrown by the repository?

Kotlin already has a [built-in `Result` type](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/), and I strongly recommend using that one instead of defining your own.

Nonetheless, if you use the built-in type, you will probably face the same problem, since the `equals` check still fails for the different exception instances.

There are several ways to solve that:

1. Define your own exception type and override the equals function to return true if they are both of the same type and have the same message.
2. Check for `expected is Error` (or with the default `Result` type that `expected.isFailure`), and then check that the messages are the same.
3. Make sure that `loginUseCase` throws exactly the same exception instance as is thrown by the repository.